# VBO with texture index buffer different than vertex index buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, vbo

I am trying to write my own OBJ importer and renderer in OpenGL (yes, I know, reinventing the wheel) and I found a problem that I don't knwo how to handle.

In an OBJ file faces are defined by a list of indices that refers to the vertices IDs that belongs to that face (and the same for texture coordinates IDs), an example of a face could be:

> f 2411/905 2414/906 2913/1463

which would mean that this face is created by vertices `2411, 2414, 3913` and texture coordinates IDs `905, 906, 1463`. And this leads to different index buffers, if I am not mistaken...

Now the question is, having both a buffer of vertices and a buffer of texture coordinates, how can I use both "at the same time", if I am only able to bing one index buffer and the indices to be used for a particular face are different for vertices and texture coordinates? Is there any trick to bind two index buffers, one for vertices and another one for texture coordinates?

And finally, just to give some code of what I've tried and that obviously doesn't work because I am binding two different `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB` before drawing..., so it ends up with random texture coodinates.

```
// TEXTURE VBO
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, texCoordBuffer);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, texIndicesBuffer);         
glIndexPointer(GL_INT, 0, 0);

// GEOMETRY VBO
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vertexBuffer);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, normalBuffer);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);                                   

glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, indicesBuffer);
glIndexPointer(GL_INT, 0, 0);

// Bind texture and draw...
```

Comment: [I asked a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696182/3-index-buffers)

Comment: [Asked and answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices)

Comment: Thanks @bobobobo and Nicol, I couldn't find these questions before. Looks we've all been there :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use separate index buffers in the way you intend to. But since you are writing your own importer, you can very well reorganise the in-memory data so that both the position and texture information are indexed the same way. This possibly means duplicating information in the process, but that cost must be put in regard to the overall bandwidth gain provided by the use of index buffers.

The recently released book [OpenGL Insights](http://openglinsights.com/) has a chapter about how to do this efficiently: [Indexing Multiple Vertex Arrays](http://openglinsights.com/performance.html#IndexingMultipleVertexArrays), by Arnaud Masserann. Even if you do not have the book or the article, the author provides [the full source code](https://github.com/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsightsCode/tree/master/Chapter%2026%20Indexing%20Multiple%20Vertex%20Arrays) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Sam! Reorganising the data was one of the solutions I was thinking of, but I thought there might be an easier way to get around this. It looked to me _too complicated_ for just an OBJ importer... ;)

Comment: Also - glIndexPointer does not do what you think it does.  http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glIndexPointer.xml

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately, an OBJ importer is fairly complicated :(

Comment: @Sam I finally got it working, reorganising the UV coordinates array in order to match the vertex index array as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @sam What about if you have multiple UV for the same vertex based on the triangle you're about to render?

Comment: @Emanuele Then the vertices need to be duplicated, one copy for each UV variation. This is usually well worth the cost.

Comment: @samhocevar Thanks. Would you suggest to fully expand them or try to see if those can be compacted once at least?

Comment: @Emanuele Yes, absolutely try to reuse vertices if they do have the same UVs; in most models this happens often. And your usual 3D authoring software does a good job at this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you *have* to do is "dupe up the data".

Say for (a contrived) example you have a square, but for some reason all 4 points of the square use the same normal:

```
v 0 0 0
v 1 0 0
v 1 1 0
v 0 1 0

vn 0 0 1

f 1//1 2//1 3//1
f 1//1 3//1 4//1
```

Great!  Now what do you do?

When you're building your vertex array, you just duplicate `vn` 4 times. So your vertex array would contain:

```
struct Vertex{
  Vector3f pos, norm ;
}  ;

vector<Vertex> verts(4) ;
verts[0] = Vertex( Vector3f( 0, 0, 0 ), Vector3f( 0, 0, 1 ) ) 
verts[1] = Vertex( Vector3f( 1, 0, 0 ), Vector3f( 0, 0, 1 ) ) 
verts[2] = Vertex( Vector3f( 1, 1, 0 ), Vector3f( 0, 0, 1 ) ) 

verts[3] = Vertex( Vector3f( 0, 0, 0 ), Vector3f( 0, 0, 1 ) ) 
verts[4] = Vertex( Vector3f( 1, 1, 0 ), Vector3f( 0, 0, 1 ) ) 
verts[5] = Vertex( Vector3f( 0, 1, 0 ), Vector3f( 0, 0, 1 ) )
```

So you see, the normal `Vector3f( 0,0,1 )` has *got* to be duplicated all over the place.  If you use an index buffer, you can reduce this to **4** verts.  But that's the best you can do with a situation like this.

Comment: Thanks @bobobobo, this is similar to what I ended up doing. I basically reordered the array of UVs in order to match the order of the vertices. In the case of having vertices with multiple UVs, I duplicated that vertex, adding an extra vertex in the list of vertices and assigning to it its original UV.